# Use SelectMany to extract value from list and pass to groups

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query where I use SelectMany on a list of lists and then GroupBy 'Name' and the 'Count' of the Lists and store the values in 'Name' and 'Count'.

```
var groups = originalList.SelectMany(fullList => fullList.ListOfItems, (fullList, details) => new { fullList.Name, fullList.ListOfItems })
                               .GroupBy(x => x.Name,
                                x => x.ListOfItems.Count())
                               .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count()});

//Do something with results        
foreach (var item in groups)
{
    var name = item.Name;
    var count = item.Count;
}
```

Now there is another paramater from the originalList that I want to pass through to the resulting groups lets call it **fullList.SomeOtherValue**.

How can I modify this above so that it is passed through also?

I want to end up withthis:

```
foreach (var item in groups)
{
    var name = item.Name;
    var count = item.Count;
    var someother = item.SomeOtherValue;  <-- I want this as well
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it sounds like something like this should work:

```
originalList.SelectMany(fullList => fullList.ListOfItems)
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.SomeOtherValue})
                .Select(g => new { g.Key.Name, g.Key.SomeOtherValue, Count = g.Count()});
```

Comment: Oleksii Aza = GENIUS :) Where does one learn these magic tricks ;)